# Latent profile analysis

Tags: latent-class

I am planning to identify profiles for individuals ($n = 200$) with experiences of domestic violence.

The 19 likert items on abuse has a 6 response format `(0 - none, 1 - once, .... 3 (3-5)...... to 6 - (20 and above)` reflecting increased frequency.

I am planning to conduct latent profile analysis treating the scale as a continuous measure. I will be summing up the individual items of the sub scales and enter it as indicators (psychological, physical ...). Each subgroup score is considered as a continuous scale. However the data is  non normal and has excess zeros specifically for some abuse types.

Would using MLR correct the non-normality or is there a better way to do like treating the responses as counts?

Answer (score 1):

The whole approach does not fit basic standards. Optimal model would simultaneously include both factors (your subscales instead of manual adding) and classes that are built on these factors. Technically, it would be a nice [mixture factor model](https://www.statmodel.com/download/psymeth.pdf), in which factor means and variances are allowed to vary across classes. Or, if you don't have a strong theory about your scales, you may start with a simple latent class analysis with your "raw" indicators - this way you won't need correction for non-normality, as you won't have this assumption.

Answering your question, MLR does not automatically correct for a non-normality, it still assumes multivariate normal distribution, it only corrects for slight deviations from it. Treating continuous variable as counts is wrong, because it implies a different distribution (Poisson instead of normal). If you observe severe non-normality you might consider transforming your data (for instance, taking logarithm or 1/x transformation).